# Website visitors details

Tags: php

I have made a PHP code that can log visitor's IP addresses, port, date, browser name in a txt file. But it doesn't shows the latest visitors details at the top. So everytime I need to scroll down a lot for seeing the users details. Is there any way to show up the visitors details at the top of the log.txt file so I will not have to scroll down everytime? Here is the full PHP code:

```
<?php
    $protocol = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $port = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $dateTime = date('Y/m/d G:i:s');

    $fh = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fh, 'IP Address: '."".$ip ."\n");
    fwrite($fh, 'Hostname: '."".$hostname ."\n");
    fwrite($fh, 'Port Number: '."".$port ."\n");
    fwrite($fh, 'User Agent: '."".$agent ."\n");
    fwrite($fh, 'HTTP Referer: '."".$ref ."\n");
    fwrite($fh, 'Date: '."".$dateTime ."\n\n");
    fclose($fh);
    ?>
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` don't rely on that.

Comment: a db would be smarter, google analytics gives you better data. nothing you log there can't be scraped from the access log.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why not use a database for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is the second parameter on the `fopen` function.

Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

You are using:

```
$fh = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
```

a means ..

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() has no effect, writes are always appended.

You can choose whichever option you want.

For example, r+ means:

> Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. `$toFile = IP;
    $toFile .= file_get_contents('log.txt');
    file_put_contents('log.txt', $toFile );`
2. > If you don't want to load the entire contents of the file into a variable, you can use PHP's [Streams](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) feature: